# Rally HTML app always forces browser scroll bar - how to avoid this?

Tags: rally, code-rally

I've noticed that when I add an HTML app in Rally/Agile Central, the height doesn't fit/adjust within the browser windows. This means that a vertical scrollbar is always added.

I'm using Chrome and Firebox, but they both have this problem.

Is there a way to limit the height of the custom app?E.g., to (height - 25) so that the browser scroll bar is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some of your code?  It might help in diagnosing what's going on.  A couple ideas though...

Are you using a layout for your app?  This often can help with scrollbar issues. 
 This guide may be helpful for learning to work with layouts: https://docs.ca.com/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/layouts

If you're just using auto layout (the default, if you didn't explicitly specify one) then you can also try adding `autoScroll: false` to your app's config.  Note this may cause your content to be clipped if you do actually need a scrollbar though.

Comment: You can just use one of the built in apps, e.g., the list app, and you also see the problem. At least on Windows with a Chrome/Firefox, I don't know on mac.

I am using auto layout - and I did try the autoscroll:false but then I can't see the button of the grid!

Comment: It has been there for the past three years at least :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an examle with the std list app - and it's the same whether there is anything to show or not.

I'm thinking that it is the HTML app that doesn't take into account that there is a page title, in this case "*test layout scroll bars" - and somehow uses the "full height" = the entire frame (I'm not an html/css expert)

[image]

Comment: oh weird-  that doesn't seem like a problem with the app itself, more like the custom page.  this is worth looking into on our end some more.